# How can two ASP.NET_SessionId cookies suddenly appear in the Cookie list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-timeout

I am having a (very) intermittent issue in a production system whereby a user will sometimes get a session timeout message while navigating from one page to another (the timeout is set to 20 minutes in the web.config file, but this happens between requests within 30 seconds).

I managed to get a Fiddler session of one of these timeouts and discovered that the request that triggered the timeout has two ASP.NET session Cookies in the header. I suspect ASP.NET is picking up the new Session ID and thinks that it is a new session.

Here is the last request that was okay:

```
POST https://************/****/****/GetBenefits HTTP/1.1
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
Accept-Language: en-au
Referer: https://********/****/****/****/eabacef3-3fc1-4c7a-a2f9-6b13294cae0d
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Host: ********
Content-Length: 272
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cookie: __utma=234635549.1047786296.1290759252.1290759252.1291100928.2; __utmz=234635549.1291100928.2.2.utmcsr=localhost:1600|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/X/****/****/****/a4ae2246-5b3c-42a9-8c43-b6f24f1838d5; SIVISITOR=MC4xMTAuMjA0ODY3NjQ1NDAwODIuMTI5MDc1OTI1MTgxMw__*; ASP.NET_SessionId=l0tsk4jwbp1v51mu3f3e4o55; __RequestVerificationToken_Lw__=JqfrynFIDnS1wc6aFWqP5WVsahQDipJzgrD/iFFfAZBUjbJX/EDrXokuyBzvNkArAjD1UBU6cKFitP1T0gI9RLUU8MIIemT2wkf0PNJhiA5dNZMNRf7PhlRpDf0zN8QCHGbd3w==

<content removed>
```

This contains one session entry: ASP.NET_SessionId=l0tsk4jwbp1v51mu3f3e4o55;

The message that returns a Session Timeout is this one:

```
POST https://********/****/****/UpdateProductCosts HTTP/1.1
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
Accept-Language: en-au
Referer: https://********/****/****/****/eabacef3-3fc1-4c7a-a2f9-6b13294cae0d
Accept: text/html, */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Host: ********
Content-Length: 351
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cookie: __utma=234635549.1047786296.1290759252.1291100928.1291267008.3; __utmz=234635549.1291100928.2.2.utmcsr=localhost:1600|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/X/****/****/****/a4ae2246-5b3c-42a9-8c43-b6f24f1838d5; SIVISITOR=MC4xMTAuMjA0ODY3NjQ1NDAwODIuMTI5MDc1OTI1MTgxMw__*; ASP.NET_SessionId=0tluyjvt4dgroov05xqalg55; __utmb=234635549.1.10.1291267008; __utmc=234635549; ASP.NET_SessionId=l0tsk4jwbp1v51mu3f3e4o55; __RequestVerificationToken_Lw__=JqfrynFIDnS1wc6aFWqP5WVsahQDipJzgrD/iFFfAZBUjbJX/EDrXokuyBzvNkArAjD1UBU6cKFitP1T0gI9RLUU8MIIemT2wkf0PNJhiA5dNZMNRf7PhlRpDf0zN8QCHGbd3w==

<content removed>
```

This contains two session entries: ASP.NET_SessionId=0tluyjvt4dgroov05xqalg55; ASP.NET_SessionId=l0tsk4jwbp1v51mu3f3e4o55;

This, in itself, is strange to me.

What I would like to know is why the second session id is appearing. How does this happen and how can I fix it?

The application is an ASP.NET MVC 1.0 based web site.

Any ideas or answers would be very welcome!

Cheers,
Adrian.

Answer (score 0):

Use IECookieViewer or Firebug to help you determine if the cookies are both from the same directory. A cookie can be from the root (or any upper) directory and another from the current application. Those cookie mgmt programs should help you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Adilson, but one of my colleagues managed to uncover the problem. Basically, there are two ASP.NET websites and the problem is occurring because of the domains they are on. 

The first site is on xxxxx.com, the second is on subdomain.xxxxx.com. The site I am having issues with is on the latter. The browser gets confused about the cookies and passes both (or least that is the behaviour we are seeing). 

Renaming the session cookie has appeared to resolve the issue.